# EmguCV DLL setup file works fine in my system but not in another system

Tags: opencv, c#-4.0, visual-c++, emgucv, setup-wizard

I have used **EmguCV Dll and OpenCV Dll** to  trigger(**switch on**) my camera when a button is pressed. The application works fine while building and compiling. After building the setup file,the application.exe file works fine in my system.In any other system the application works fine till the Camera is triggered, **the moment camera is triggered, the application crashes** . First I thought maybe the issue is with 32 bit and 64 bit. I built two separate setup files specific for 64 bit and 32 bit and still the application crashes while triggering the camera. I also read that  **Microsoft C++ Redistribute Package** has to be installed and I tried installing that, Still the application failed and did not trigger the camera. Kindly help regarding this issue

These are my logs :-

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: aindrasmartattendance.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5523aef5
  Problem Signature 04: Emgu.CV
  Problem Signature 05: 2.4.10.1939
  Problem Signature 06: 548278fa
  Problem Signature 07: 3ac
  Problem Signature 08: 14
  Problem Signature 09: System.TypeInitialization
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    16393
  Additional Information 1: dac2
  Additional Information 2: dac2dba5ddc5d0577434255af55618b7
  Additional Information 3: f0bd
  Additional Information 4: f0bd2045bac4d1dc98365de98e6112a2

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to build emgucv in 64 bit aswell

Comment: Correct, I even built in  64 bit using 64 bit Dlls and I found that the apllication.exe is working in systems which have visual studio and not in any other system. I want my  application to work in any system which has windows OS.

Comment: If you have some logs then it il be very useful to debug.

Comment: Sorry for the delay,